# Alarm clock in Raphael JS - getting user input value and comparing to current time

Tags: javascript, raphael, alarm

I am trying to implement an alarm onto my digital clock which I have already built in Raphael Js, but cannot seem to get it working. I am trying to get the value of my 'display' text variable and compare it to the time that the user has input in an input field.

```
var alarmclock;
var alarmtime = document.getElementById('alarm').value();
alarmclock = alarmtime;
```

I have an input field with an id 'alarm' in my html script.
My 'display' variable below has already been declared and is working, showing the current time in 24 hour digital format. However I want to get the value of that display variable, and compare it to the user input in my 'alarm' input field. So I tried:

```
display.attr({text:  (h+multiplier) + ":" + m + ":" + s});

if(document.getElementById('display').value() == alarmclock){
    display.attr({text: 'wake up!'});
};
```

but it doesn't work and shows the error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null".

just in case it might help, here is the declaration of the display variable near the top of the document:

```
var display = paper.text(200, 282, " ");
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing jQuery syntax with native javascript. For example, `document.getElementById('alarm').value();` should just be `document.getElementById('alarm').value` and `display.attr({text: 'wake up!'});` needs to be `display.setAttribute('text', 'wake up!')`

Comment: im using Raphael Js though, which has slightly different syntax to standard Javascript in some aspects

Comment: Right, but if you're going to use that syntax, don't you need to pass the object into `Raphael(element)` to expose those methods?

Comment: correct, I have already done that in my document, I don't wanna copy all my code here because there is loads of it! I have already built a watch that works correctly in Rapahel Js, I'm just tryin to implement an alrm to it, but can't seem to get this aspect of it working.